# Authorization With ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I'm not sure whether I coined the term right above in title but below is my problem summary.

I have developed REST API's using ASP.NET WebAPI with Identity for Authentication.

For E.g. say I have a Company API lying at `http://<myurl>/api/Companies` for GET and POST and `http://<myurl>/api/Companies/{id}` for GETBYID, PUT and DELETE.

While testing the API's I found that once a user is Authenticated (by Token), s/he can edit any company.

I'd like to restrict users to edit / delete companies (and other entities too) on which s/he belongs to (according to the logical structure of table).

**Solution On My Mind :**
The first idea comes to my mind is using `ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());` to find the user who's requesting the operation and then find the Company s/he belongs to say by `user.CompanyID` and match with the Payload if s/he is trying to edit / delete or perform some other operation on same entity he belongs to.

Yes, for different entities it'll be `user.EntityID`. But is this the right approach to do this?

Because this way, I have to write this kind of code on all my controller Edit and Delete operation.

I know, ASP.NET cannot restrict things on logical structure. Such as here in my case, it cannot determine, whether user is trying to edit the company s/he belongs to or not, as that's something logical to DB Relation. But is there anything kind of `[Authorize]` attribute, that I can develop which will contain the above logic instead of cluttering the controller?

**UPDATE :**
Not sure if everyone is understanding the situation, but here's some more story to clarify. It's a SaaS App in Cloud with Multi-Tenant Database. So each and every Company have their own set of Users and other Entities who should not be able to access Entities outside their Company (as per table relationship)

The API's are being consumed by Front-End WebApp, so Restricting by Views are what I'm doing for now. But I'm concerned about what if someone just inspects the JS File and calls the API's directly?

I need something to limit the user within it's entities only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to slice this, but I think the most secure would be to setup SQL [`Views`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175503.aspx) that allow your users to access data from the underlying tables, filtering the data based on the user / organization / roles / claims. If you're not familiar with views, you basically create your underlying tables structure, then views are created as a layer above the tables, each of them is generated via a query, then your top level app can simply query the views.

You may create a custom `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` class to apply additional filters declaratively (just like how `[Authorize]` works). The following would give you an `[AuthorizeActive]` filter that you could apply to actions which would check the users ID against the database to ensure they are `active` on every request:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;


public class AuthorizeActiveAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public AuthorizeActiveAttribute() {
        _userService = Injection.Get<IUserService>();
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));

        if (SkipAuthorization(filterContext)) return;
        var userId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current?.Identity?.GetUserId<int>();
        if (userId != null && userId > 0 && _userService.GetUserStatus((int) userId)) {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else {
            filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }


    private static bool SkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext) {
        var hasAnonymousAction = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Count > 0;
        var hasAnonymousController = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Count > 0;
        return hasAnonymousAction || hasAnonymousController;
    }
}
```

In addition you can setup a base api controller containing common logic for authorization (perhaps you want all APIs to be authorized by default):

```
/// <summary>
/// Base controller for resource related API calls.
/// </summary>
[AuthorizeActive]
public abstract class ResourceController : ApiController {
    public bool IsAuthorized => User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true;
    public int ActualUserId => GetIntegerClaimValue("actualuserid");
    public int UserId => GetIntegerClaimValue("userid");
    public int UserTypeId => GetIntegerClaimValue("usertypeid");
    public UserTypes UserType => (UserTypes)UserTypeId;
    public int ActualOrganizationId => GetIntegerClaimValue("actualorganizationid");
    public int OrganizationId => GetIntegerClaimValue("organizationid");
    public string Fingerprint => GetClaimValue("fingerprint");

    protected string GetClaimValue(string shortName) => (User?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?.Claims?.GetValue($"http://schemas.example.com/identity/claims/{shortName}");
    protected int GetIntegerClaimValue(string shortName) => Convert.ToInt32(GetClaimValue(shortName));
}

public HomeController : ResourceController {
}
```

This example is pulling custom claims out of the .NET user identity that correspond to the users organization, whether they are impersonating, etc.

Now, all of your API calls are authorized and secured to only allow users who are active in your database by default, to allow access anonymously, decorate the method with `[AllowAnonymous]`. Within your controllers that inherit `ResourceController` you will always have access to any of its protected properties, making it simple to grab the users organization ID and use it in your queries.

Comment: This would require the system to extend the identity/auth system through to the database layer, which may be considered a bad design.

Comment: Additionally, in many database systems (such as those that can't integrate with a Directory service, such as Neo4j) this is not a possible solution at all, and Enterprise Integration is difficult in many databases - and is flat-out impossible in publically-accessible web-application scenarios.

Comment: This is in fact exactly how Microsoft themselves architected security for [Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531182.aspx). While it may be a larger undertaking, I doubt many would agree that locking down the database at the database level is a "bad design". To the contrary, it wards against security loopholes.

Comment: I say it's a bad design because it means the persistence layer is now responsible for enforcing business acces rules. But yes, it's subjective.

Comment: I agree in that I wouldn't put a lot of the logic at this layer, I would strictly use views to create very low level barriers on data, such as filtering all data in a multi-tenant database by the users organization ID, which would completely eliminate the chance that organizations could seep data to other orgs. The alternative to this approach will require adding organization ID checks to every single query you write at the ORM level.

Comment: The problem is mine is multi-tenant database, and it's not a WebApp instead a API App, so anyone can easily see the API's by checking the JS Files of the Web App (Inspect Element). Currently I'm using this approach only to limit the data to user's organization only. But what if one checks the API's and request directly by calling the API?

Comment: But this is just doing what `[Authorize]` or `[AllowAnonymous]` does. But my requirement is to restrict them to access other person's data on a multi tenant DB. Correct me if I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar - I would have a look at some of the suggestions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). There is an example on there of creating a view specifically for multi-tenant database architecture that limits the scope of data an org is able to pull.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cchamberlain :)

Comment: @cchamberlain Well, I'm sorry if I'm missing something. But I don't want to determine whether the user is active or what. What I want is the user to prevenent accessing data of other companies in a multi tenant DB. Such as user tries to PUT a company details which he doesn't belongs to. I need to restrict that.

Comment: That would be best done with the first method I described (views). Otherwise it's extremely dependent on your ORM and will vary by implementation.

Comment: @cchamberlain But in a WebAPI App, someone can easily get the API's by inspect element and then can pass different ID say 2 instead of 1 (from view) to update different entity. Even though I'm restricting the view, but then to restrict this thing, I need to write logic at every controller which seems not a good idea.

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar - This is very dependent on your SQL architecture and choice of ORM. I typically create a services layer that sits behind the controllers, and you could implement that sort of logic in that services layer. Alternatively, if the data should not be shared across tenants, consider creating multiple databases / use schemas to delineate different organizations data. If its a user specific claim that prevents that user from updating the other record, you should put that logic either in the controller or in the services layer right behind it. I'd recommend dapper-dot-net over EF.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cchamberlain :) That helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct, custom access rules have to be implemented as part of your business logic, however you can simplify things somewhat.

For example, if some of your entities all have a `CompanyId` property which indicates that they belong to a particular company, then you could define `IHasCompanyOwner` and then have a single method to check access:

```
interface IHasCompanyOwner {
    Int32 CompanyId { get;  }
}


public partial class Widget : IHasCompanyOwner {}
public partial class Shop   : IHasCompanyOwner {}

private Boolean CanAccessCompanyEntity(IHasCompanyOwner entity) {P
    return entity.CompanyId == ((MyUserIdentity)this.User.Identity).CompanyId;
}

public ActionResult GetWidget(Int32 widgetId) {

    Widget w = this.database.GetWidget(widgetId);
    if( !CanAccessCompanyEntity( w ) ) return this.Http403("You don't have permission to access this Widget");
}

public ActionResult GetShop(Int32 shopId) {

    Shop s = this.database.GetShop(shopId);
    if( !CanAccessCompanyEntity( s ) ) return this.Http403("You don't have permission to access this Shop");
}
```

Comment: This seems reasonable a bit.